# How to blur the edges of a surface in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'd like to blur the edges of a surface in a "gradient fashion", in Pygame.

Here is an example of the desired effect where we have :

- No blur on first image
- Medium blur on second square
- High blur on third square

[image of blur effects desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deIh4.png)

Pygame has 2 functions to blur surfaces : `pygame.transform.box_blur` and `pygame.transform.gaussian_blur`. However they don't have perform a gradient blur between the surface and the screen like in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `Surface` with a transparent background (`pygame.SRCALPHA`) that is slightly larger than your image. Then you can `blit` your image onto the surface and blur it:

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, image.get_width()+100, image.get_height()+100)
blur_image = pygame.Surface(rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
blur_image.blit(image, image.get_rect(center = rect.center))
```

If you then `blit` this `Surface` onto the display, you get a gradient transition.

When you look in the [pygame documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html) you'll find, that `pygame.transform.box_blur` and `pygame.transform.gaussian_blur` does not exist ins Pygame (2.5.1 at the time of writing) but only [pygame-ce](https://pyga.me/). However, you can create your own blur function with [PLI `Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html):

```py
def blur_image(surf, radius):
    pil_string_image = pygame.image.tostring(surf, "RGBA",False)
    pil_image = Image.frombuffer("RGBA", surf.get_size(), pil_string_image)
    pil_blurred = pil_image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=radius))
    blurred_image = pygame.image.fromstring(pil_blurred.tobytes(), pil_blurred.size, pil_blurred.mode)
    return blurred_image.convert_alpha()
```

---

Minimal example

[image]

```py
import pygame
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *background.get_size(), (32, 32, 32), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
[pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect) for rect, color in tiles]

def blur_image(surf, radius):
    pil_string_image = pygame.image.tostring(surf, "RGBA",False)
    pil_image = Image.frombuffer("RGBA", surf.get_size(), pil_string_image)
    pil_blurred = pil_image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=radius))
    blurred_image = pygame.image.fromstring(pil_blurred.tobytes(), pil_blurred.size, pil_blurred.mode)
    return blurred_image.convert_alpha()

def blur_image_edges(surf, radius):
    rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, surf.get_width()+radius*4, surf.get_height()+radius*4)
    blur_surf = pygame.Surface(rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    blur_surf.blit(surf, surf.get_rect(center = rect.center))
    blurred_image = blur_image(blur_surf, radius)
    return blurred_image

image = pygame.Surface((200, 200))
image.fill('red')
blurred_image = blur_image_edges(image, 20)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    window.blit(blurred_image, blurred_image.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: You're looking in the wrong (as in you're not gonna find this there) pygame's docs, pg/pg has never had blur functions (to my knowledge), pygame-ce on the other hand does have them https://pyga.me/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.box_blur

Comment: `box_blur`and `gaussian_blur`does exist in pygame-ce. However the answer logic remain the same, you'll need to have a larger surface with transparent pixels to perform the blur upon.

Answer (score 3):

If you use pygame-ce, you have access to the new functions `pygame.transform.box_blur` and `pygame.transform.gaussian_blur`, to achieve blurs without needing to pull in other libraries.

Looking at the image you provided it seems like your need would be met by a region-specific blur setting.

Let's use this example image:

[image: Lord of the rings example]

If we blur specific regions separately it could look like this: (It would look better in your example since your squares are separated by gaps)

[image: LOTR region blur]

This code works by making subsurfaces of the original image in the desired blur regions, blurring the subsurfaces, and then blitting them back to the main surface.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

img = pygame.image.load("lord_small.png").convert_alpha()

def blur_region(region, amount):
    img.blit(pygame.transform.box_blur(img.subsurface(region), amount), region)

third = img.get_width() // 3
blur_region([0, 0, third, img.get_height()], 4)
blur_region([third, 0, third, img.get_height()], 8)
blur_region([third * 2, 0, img.get_width() - third * 2, img.get_height()], 12)

while True:
    screen.fill("black")
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise SystemExit

    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

However, how could we add a true gradient to the blur? My solution is to make a blurred copy of the original surface, then gradually transition from showing more of the original surface to more of the blurred surface, by creating special gradient-opacity surfaces and using those to modulate the amount of which is shown.

[image: LOTR gradient blur]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

img = pygame.image.load("lord_small.png").convert_alpha()
img_blurred = pygame.transform.box_blur(img, 4)

alpha_surf = pygame.Surface((256, 1), pygame.SRCALPHA)
for i in range(256):
    alpha_surf.set_at((i, 0), (255,255,255,i))
alpha_surf = pygame.transform.scale(alpha_surf, img.get_size())
alpha_surf_reciprocal = pygame.transform.flip(alpha_surf, True, False)

img.blit(alpha_surf_reciprocal, (0,0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
img_blurred.blit(alpha_surf, (0,0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)

combined_img = pygame.Surface(img.get_size(), depth=32)
combined_img.blit(img, (0,0))
combined_img.blit(img_blurred, (0,0))

while True:
    screen.fill("purple")

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise SystemExit
        
    screen.blit(combined_img, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Indeed `box_blur`and `gaussian_blur`does exists in pygame-ce, the version I'm using. However you misunderstood what I meant. I'm looking at creating a blur / "gradient" between the background and the image, resulting in image edges blurred. Your images doesn't show a blur/transition between the screen the image is drawed upon, and the image. Look at the image linked in the original post.

Comment: To achieve a blur between the background and the image, blit the image to the background and then use my blur_region function on the Rect region you blit to.